# How can I be able to change the object starting position but also to update it's position when moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TransitionState
    {
        None,
        MovingTowards,
        Transferring
    }

    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public Transform navi;
    public Transform player;
    public bool isChild = false;
    public AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    public float duration = 10.0f;
    public bool go = false;

    private float t;
    private Transform originTransform;
    private float timer;
    private TransitionState state = TransitionState.MovingTowards;
    private Vector3 originPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        t = 0.0f;

        curve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
        originPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                    var v = destinationTransform.position - transform.position;
                    if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                    {
                        state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                        originTransform = destinationTransform;
                        timer = 0;
                        return;
                    }

                    t += Time.deltaTime;
                    float s = t / duration;

                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition,
                        destinationTransform.position, curve.Evaluate(s));
                    break;

                case TransitionState.Transferring:
                    timer += Time.deltaTime;
                    this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originTransform.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);

                    if (timer >= 1.0f)
                    {
                        this.transform.parent = destinationTransform;
                        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                        isChild = true;

                        state = TransitionState.None;
                        this.enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    this.enabled = false;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set the starting position before running the game in the editor when I drag the transform to some position when running the game it's changing back to the originPosition if I mark not to use the line at the Start()

```
//originPosition = transform.position;
```

Than it will start from the other side at all.
I want it to start moving from where I set it at the start position.

Moving the line

```
originPosition = transform.position;
```

To the Update() is also not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If transform.position returns something different from what you’ve set in edit mode, it’s affected by something else on `Start()` or  `Awake()` in some script. Also it is possible, that some script sets public `go` variable to true on awake.